# Translating Rows into Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have One column with a couple thousand rows of data that looks like the following in Excel 2010.

[image: Table with values]

I'd like to move the data into five columns starting over every five rows, to look like the following

[image]

Comment: Check Help and see if there's a "pivot" tool or command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*5,0)
```

and copy both across and downwards.

If necessary, format your date cells properly

**EDIT#1:**

Using similar formulas, it is easy to map any single column or single row into a 2-D table.

It is equally easy to map a 2-D table into a single column or single rrow.

Comment: This appears to only work for the first 31 records before the columns begin to 'mix' together. That is they shift to the right one and the one at the end shifts to the far left column.

Comment: Nevermind this was actually the leaking of one data value into multiple rows.

Comment: @infamoustrey  See my **EDIT#1**